# IO Exception was unhandled error

Tags: vb.net

Code:

[browser.vb]

```
...
Private Sub Browser_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(DefaultHomePageSavedLocation) = False Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\ToolBoxData\TinyBrowser\")
            File.Create(DefaultHomePageSavedLocation)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(DefaultHomePageSavedLocation, "http://hk.yahoo.com", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

[setting.vb]

```
...
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\ToolBoxData\TinyBrowser\Home.txt")
    File.Create("C:\ToolBoxData\TinyBrowser\Home.txt")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\ToolBoxData\TinyBrowser\Home.txt", TextBox1.Text, True)
End Sub
```

So a error message was shown:

> IO Exception was unhandled.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [File.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see that it is a function which returns "A FileStream that provides read/write access to the file specified in path." This implies that the file is open. If you look at the docs for the [FileSystem.WriteAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see that you do not need to create the file beforehand, and there is no overload which takes a filestream as a parameter.

So, take out the `File.Create` lines.

Please remember to tell us which line generated the error in future.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I will test it now and see if it's ok.

Comment: @Jamie You're welcome :) I shall decline your kind offer of trying out your program. Please note that you should be storing your application data somewhere like a sub-folder of one the folders given in [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If your program tried to create a directory in the root of the C: drive on my computer, it would fail.