# Visual Basic: Checking if file exists, if not, create the file

Tags: if-statement, text-files, createfile, basic

This is the code. It checks if the file in path exists, if not, it creates the file. I'm getting this error message all the time and I don't know why. Maybe I should close the System.IO.Directory.Exists? If yes, how do I do that? Just so you know, I'm creating a text file.

**The code**

```
If Not (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then
        Dim fs3 As FileStream = File.Create(path)
    End If
```

**This is the error message I get:**

Process can't use the file (path) because some other process is using this file at the moment.

Comment: I suspect the reason behind the problem is the same as in [IO Exception was unhandled error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577442/io-exception-was-unhandled-error/22577562#comment34384863_22577562). Otherwise, is there are reason that you are using `Directory.Exists` instead of `File.Exists`?

Comment: It works now. I would never have thought of that, so thank you random stranger! Thumbs up for you.

Answer (score -1):

The file is used by other processes hence it can't be overwritten. I suggest you delete the file first.

```
Dim path As String = "put your path"

For Each path In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\WINDOWS\TEMP")
System.IO.File.Delete(path)
Next path

Dim fs3 As FileStream = File.Create(path)
```

Be certain that you have full rights [under properties] to the folder.