# Check if file exists, using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to know if a file exists, using Visual Basic 6 (not VB.NET). So far, I have this, as gleaned from a few different snippets I googled up:

```
If Len(Dir("C:\frogs\dogs.txt")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "File Found!"
Else
    MsgBox "File Does Not Exist!"
End If
```

That's it. The whole script. Doesn't work. When I run it, I get "Type Mismatch: 'Dir'" What am I doing wrong?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936426/visual-basic-checking-if-file-exists-if-not-create-the-file) appears to be for a later version of VB? Maybe it's relevant?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've see this happen when you have something like `Dim Dir` in your app or is this VBScript?

Comment: That's the entire script. There is no app. I'm not completely sure about the VB nomenclature though, so maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: VbScript doesn't have the `Dir`command.  Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031497/how-to-verify-if-file-exist-with-vb-script).